# HTML Control to add email addresses

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

What HTML control can I use on a razor page to add recipient email addresses? I want to have something like an add button that will add a text-box or something each time.

Edit: I would prefer not to have something like a text-area with emails semi-colon delimited.

Comment: So why don't you implement an add button that will add a textbox each time? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its better to use jquery, you have nice example here:

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a javascript for that! just reffer this below link!

http://blog.mdsohelrana.com/2008/07/02/how-to-add-html-control-dynamically-using-javascript-dom/